# Is there any 100% solid and working way of finding text or csv file encoding

Tags: file, csv, encoding, utf-8

Is there any 100% solid and working way of finding the encoding of a file. I have tried BOM but it fails sometimes, is there any other perfect way, or is it impossible altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Virtually any random accumulation of bytes is valid in most single byte encodings like ISO-8859 et al. It may yield nonsensical characters, but it's *valid*. Trying different single byte encodings will yield *different* nonsense, but it's all *valid* as far as the encoding is concerned. So you're then moving into Natural Language Processing territory to figure out whether a certain sequence of nonsense seems more sensical than another, and you start scoring your guesses with a confidence index. That's not a 100% solid way by definition, it's guesswork.

The only thing you can do with certainty is *rule out* certain encodings which have stricter rules; e.g. not every sequence of bytes is valid in UTF-8. If you try to decode it as UTF-8 and the decoder complains, you can rule out that encoding. That just leaves hundreds of other candidates…